# AVAudioPlayerNode scheduleBuffer playing some glitchy noise while audio transmission

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I am trying to use scheduleBuffer, audio is transmitting also but at receiver end playing with some glitchy sound
[image]

```
private func convertAudioToPCMBuffer(clip: Audio) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
    var PCMBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer()
    
    guard let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat( commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: clip.sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: false) else {  return nil }
    
    guard let audioPCMBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer( pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: clip.frameCapacity) else {  return nil }
    
    audioPCMBuffer.frameLength = audioPCMBuffer.frameCapacity
    guard let channelData = audioPCMBuffer.floatChannelData else { return nil }
    
    let shortFloats = self.audioCompressor.decompress(byteArray: [UInt8](clip.audio))
    
    let leftChannelIndex: Int = 0
    if(shortFloats.count >= audioPCMBuffer.frameLength) {
        for i in 0 ..< Int(audioPCMBuffer.frameLength) {
            channelData[leftChannelIndex][i] = shortFloats[i] // ptr to audioPCMBuffer's Core Audio AudioBufferList
        }
    }

    if clip.sampleRate != self.playbackSampleRate {
        PCMBuffer = AudioSessionConfigurator.convertSampleRate( inSampleRate: clip.sampleRate, outSampleRate: self.playbackSampleRate, inBuffer: audioPCMBuffer
        )
    } else {
        PCMBuffer = audioPCMBuffer
    }
    return PCMBuffer
```

Comment: can you show how you're configuring the buffer?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Could you please check above PCMBuffer conversion